# PHP-FFMPEG Encoding error - How to use -stric experimental?

Tags: php, ffmpeg-php

Im trying to convert a m3u8 file but im getting encoding error.

How do i get the ffmpeg output from the thrown exception to check where is the error?
this is the php code.

```
$ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create();
            $video = $ffmpeg->open("/home/enrico/clipper/tmp/streamers/Antonio/" . $video_id);
            $format = new FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264();
            $format->setInitialParameters(array('-bsf:a',  'aac_adtstoasc' , '-acodec', 'copy', '-vcodec', 'copy'));
            $video->save($format, "playlista.mp4");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that library, but from looking at the source, it seems that you can check the previous exception, which apparently in many cases will be an instance of [**`\Alchemy\BinaryDriver\Exception\ExecutionFailureException`**](https://github.com/alchemy-fr/BinaryDriver/blob/v5.2.0/src/Alchemy/BinaryDriver/Exception/ExecutionFailureException.php), which in turn has a `getErrorOutput()` method that will return the process' error output.

```php
$catchedFfmpegException->getPrevious()->getErrorOutput()
```

Check [**the source code**](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg/blob/v0.18.0/src/FFMpeg/Media/AbstractVideo.php#L60-L114) to figure what exactly is going on. Dumping the exception object should also give you some insight.